# How can I return Prime Numbers into an Output File?

Tags: java

So far I have the below code.... I import a File with numbers and test to see if they are prime or not.  I am supposed to then output the prime numbers into a separate file, but I am unable to move the numbers from the "isPrime" Method ( which tests if the #'s are prime) to the "Main" Method.

```
public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException
{

int x, input;
String filename, filename2;
Scanner k = new Scanner (System.in);
System.out.println("Hello, please enter an input file name!");
filename = k.nextLine();
System.out.println("Hello, please enter an output file name!");
filename2 = k.nextLine();
File file = new File(filename);
Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);

while (inputFile.hasNext())
{
    input = inputFile.nextInt();

inputFile.close();
isPrime(input);
}

PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter("C\\Desktop\\"+filename2);
}

public static boolean isPrime(int n) {

 for(int i=2;i<n;i++) {
    if(n%i==0)

       return false;
}
return outputFile.println(n);
```

}

Comment: *Step 1:* Indent your code for human readability. --- *Step 2:* Use try-with-resources to ensure your file streams get closed. --- *Step 3:* Use the return value from the `isPrime()` call, to decide *there* whether to write the number to the output file.

Answer (score 0):

There is some mistakes in your code:

1. Use try-with-resource to take advantage of `AutoCloseable` interface.
2. Follow fields name conventions, to make the code more readable.
3. Make `isPrime(int)` return `boolean` and depend on it decide to write number or not.

I have rewrite your code, Look at this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner userInputScanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please enter the path for numbers file: ");
    String inputNumberFilePath = userInputScanner.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Please enter the path for the output file: ");
    String outputNumberFilePath = userInputScanner.nextLine();

    try (Scanner inputNumberFileReader = new Scanner(new File(inputNumberFilePath)); PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter(outputNumberFilePath);) {
        while (inputNumberFileReader.hasNext()) {
            int num = inputNumberFileReader.nextInt();
            if (isPrime(num)) {
                outputFile.println(num);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    } finally {
        if (userInputScanner != null) {
            userInputScanner.close();
        }
    }
}

public static boolean isPrime(int num) {
    for (int i = 2; i < num; i++) {
        if (num % i == 0)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: remember that you have to enter the correct path for each input and output files, an exception will appear if the file is not exist.

Comment: 1. No need to initialise variables to null. 2. There is no benefit of splitting the declaration and initialisation of variables, e.g. `filename`. Only the disadvantage of having more lines and harder to read code. 3. You should initialise the files in a try-with-resources or before the whole try. Otherwise you might get NPEs in the `finally` clause, e.g. when the error occurs on the first line in the `try` block. 4. Your variable names do not convey the right meaning or none at all, e.g. a `Scanner` instance should not be named `inputFile`. Same goes for `filename1` and `filename2` or `k`.

Comment: Yes, I have tried to use his variables name so that he don't get confused, but you are right, any one could use the code, so it is better to write it in the proper way, thanks.

Comment: "Here, I've rewritten the code for you but I won't explain you what your did wrong" answers are not in the spirit of Stack Overflow.

Comment: @kryger thanks, I've rewritten the code in the proper way.